# AppleScript: Get the name of the current font of Microsoft Word

Tags: macos, ms-word, applescript

I am new to Applescript, I would like to get the name of the current font of Microsoft Word. I tried the following code:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    tell selection
        tell font
            name
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

But executing this script prints the following error message:

> error: "Can't get name of font." number -1728 from name of <<class
> w137>>

What's the problem of my code? And what do -1728 and w137 mean?

Comment: 1728 usually means AppleScript does not have access to the application being called. In current versions of Mac Office, AppleScript access is very limited due to sandboxing ... that could be the problem I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me using macOS Big Sur and Word version 16.34

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    set fontUsed to name of font object of selection
end tell
```

Comment: Yes. It's *font object*, not *font*. I missed *object* in my code, adding *object* also works in my code.

Comment: Why does it have the be "font object"? If I say "word object" it tells me that object is undefined. But in the dictionary, both "font" and "word" look the same in the Microsoft Word dictionary.